# How to solve BeanDefinitionStoreException caused by FileNotFoundException in SPRING?(Netbeans IDE)

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm creating a very simple java application using spring. But the application is not able to open the configuration file(config.xml).

I'm using nebeans IDE 8.2 jdk8 version

Here is the code:

```
package com.prasad.spring.springcore;


import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Prasad-pc
 */
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");  //  configuration file name
        Employee emp = (Employee) ctx.getBean("emp");
        System.out.println("Employee ID: " + emp.getId());
        System.out.println("Employee Name: " + emp.getName());
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.prasad.spring.springcore.Test.main(Test.java:21)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 13 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The "config.xml" is present in src/main/java directory

Comment: `config.xml` either does not exist, or is in the wrong location.

Comment: Should be in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer, please upvote and accept (tick) it.  Remember you get a few reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The `config.xml` file has to be in `src/main/resources` directory whereas in the above case it is on `src/main/java`

Answer (score 0):

`src/main/java` should only contain Java classes.  Anything else in there will be ignored.

`src/main/resources` should contain anything that you want included in its current form, like XML files.